# How can I use a QLIkView set analysis expression in script?

Tags: data-analysis, qlikview

I extend a QLikView application, that has two set analysis expressions used in the visualizations of the app. Now I need to assign the results of the expressions to a variabele but the problem is that the expressions aren't accepted in the script.

My two expressions are :

```
NUM(SUM({$<Boekjaar = {$(=MAX(Boekjaar))}, PeriodeId = {"<=$(=MAX({<Boekjaar={$(=MAX(Boekjaar))}>} PeriodeId))"},  BalansOmschrijving1 = {"Overzicht kengetallen"}, BalansOmschrijving3 = {"Tussenrekeningen voor BTW"} >} Saldo), '###.###.###.##0')

Num(Sum({$<BalansOmschrijving2 = {"Liquide Middelen"}>} Bedrag * isDebetBoeking) - Sum({$<BalansOmschrijving2 = {"Liquide Middelen"}>} Bedrag * isCreditBoeking),'0,00')
```

The two tables where the expressions are used :

[image]

[image]

My goal is to use the expressions in my script and have the possibility to put a value from field JaarMaand into the expressions and calculates 'Saldo liquide middelen' and 'BTW verrekening' belong to the JaarMaand.

Comment: the simple answer is: its NOT possible to use `set analysis` in the script.

Comment: if you want to to calculate `Saldo liquide middelen` and `BTW verrekening` as a static numbers (in the script) and use these pre-calculated numbers in the app then this is another story and its most likely possible with some data manipulations (but you will loose the dynamic calculation of these numbers based on selections)